# Metrics problem

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let be $(X,d)$ a metric space, then, you have:
$$D(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb{R}|\quad \forall x,y\in X (|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x,y)\leq f(x)+f(y))\} $$
Show that the function
$$d_D(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}$$
is well defined and it's a metric

For being well defined I have to show that the $\sup\{B\}$ exists, considering $B=\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}$

1. $B \subset \mathbb{R}$
2. $B\neq \emptyset \quad$ because if I take and $x_o\in X\quad $ then $f(x_o),g(x_o)\quad$ are well defined, same case por $|f(x_o)-g(x_o)|\quad $it exists and thats why $|f(x_o)-g(x_o)|\in B$
3. $B\quad$ is bounded superiorly ... The  problem its that, I can not see why does $\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}\quad $ is bounded superiorly to say that the sup exists.I would appreciate a lot if someone helps me.

Now, to show that $d_D(f,g)\quad $is a metric I got to show 3 things:

(1)
$$d_D(f,g)=0 \Longleftrightarrow \sup\{B\}=0\Longleftrightarrow \forall b\in B (b\leq 0)$$

See that $\forall b\in B (\quad0\leq b) \Longrightarrow \qquad \quad 0\leq b\leq 0 \Longleftrightarrow b=0\Longleftrightarrow \forall x\in X(|f(x)-g(x)|=0) \Longleftrightarrow \forall x\in X(f(x)=g(x))$

That's why $d_D(f,g)=0 \Longleftrightarrow f=g$

(2)

Then, lets take $f,g\in D(X) \Longrightarrow d_D(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}=\sup\{|g(x)-f(x)|:x\in X\}=d_D(g,f)$

(3)

For triangle inequality i try this:
if you take  $h\in D(X) \rightarrow\forall x \in X(|f(x)-g(x)|\leq |f(x)-h(x)|+|h(x)-g(x)|\quad $

then, $ \{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}\leq \{|f(x)-h(x)|:x\in X\}+\{|h(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}$

then: $\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}\leq\sup(\{|f(x)-h(x)|:x\in X\}+\{|h(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\})=\sup\{|f(x)-h(x)|:x\in X\}+\sup\{|h(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}$

And thats why $d_D(f,g)\leq d_D(f,h)+d_D(h,g)$

The  problem its that, I can not see why does $\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in X\}\quad $ is bounded superiorly to say that the sup exists.I would appreciate a lot if someone helps me.